# How to investigate 5MB+ datasets in RStudio's source editor?

Tags: r, csv, dataset, rstudio, filesize

**My question:**

**Can I change the parameters in R to use the source editor to also view >5MB data sets in R?**

***If not, what is your advice?***

**Background:**

I recently stopped looking at data in Excel and switched to R entirely. As I did in Excel and still prefer to do in R, I like to look at the entire frame and then decide on filters.

**Problem:** Working with the World Development Indicators (WDI) data set which is over 100MB, opening it in the source editor does not work. **`View(df)` opens an empty tab in RStudio** as also shown below:

[image: Screenshot from RStudio]

R threw another error when I selected the data set from the Files Tab in column on the right of RStudio which read:

*The selected file 'wdi.csv' is too large to open in the source editor (the file is 104.5 MB and the maximum file size is 5MB).*

**Solutions?**

My alter ego would tell me to increase the threshold of datasets' file size for the source editor, so I could investigate it there. In brief: change 5 to 200 MB. My alter ego would also tell me that I would probably encounter performance issues (since I am using a MacAir).

How I resolved the issue:
I used `head()` and `dplyr's glimpse()` to get a better idea, but ended up looking at the wdi matrix in excel and then filtered it out in R. Newly created dataframes could be opened in the source editor without any problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you wanting to look at? You can try using `head()` and `tail()` to see the top and bottom 6 lines. Further you can add an argument into either of those `n=` to declare a number of lines to look at. If you want to see into the middle of the data use `[ , ]` to declare the rows and columns, for instance `dataset[500:500,]` to see all the data between row 500 ad 550 and all columns. Hope that helps. Generally you don't "view" the data in that way in R, having come from excel, I know old habits die hard!

Comment: I would suggest to either read in the dataset then view it with `View()` or to use a spreadsheet application like Excel, OpenOffice Calc, etc. You could read it in with `data.table` since it's large. R and RStudio are spreadsheet applications, they are made to work with their own data types (though they are certainly meant to *import* from spreadsheets). Support for viewing data even with `View()` is actually quite minimal. In my opinion RStudio is just the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: A potential solution is to build a reusable Shiny app and use `DT` to view your data. `DT` also comes with filtering and sorting functions. I've tried it on the WDI data and it's pretty fast. One limitation is that you'll view data paginated, as `DT` uses HTML and it will be slow displaying huge data tables on one page, but you can experiment and change the page length as needed.

Comment: To add to the above, I just usually use `View` with some filter for larger datasets. E.g. `View(head())`, or `View(dat['Country Name' == "Arab World"],)`.